# Плитка для резинового макета

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли `js`-скрипт, аналогичный [`masonry`](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html), но применимый для резинового макета? То есть чтобы при изменении ширины экрана ширина блоков менялась плавно

Если да, то поделитесь ссылочкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/fluid.html

При инициализации плагина, задаёте необходимое количество столбцов в контейнере с блоками, а самим блокам в CSS задаёте не фиксированную ширину, а в процентах.